# COBOL LINUX - when compiling, receiving errors

Tags: linux, command, cobol, gnucobol

When attempting to compile I get these numerous errors as seen below:

```
user@DESKTOP-57BGLNH:~$ pwd
/home/user
user@DESKTOP-57BGLNH:~$ ls
COBOL               testdoc.cob
user@DESKTOP-57BGLNH:~$ cobc -x testdoc.cob
assignment1.cob:1: error: invalid indicator 'f' at column 7
assignment1.cob:2: error: invalid indicator 'm' at column 7
assignment1.cob:4: error: invalid indicator 'n' at column 7
assignment1.cob:5: error: invalid indicator 'u' at column 7
assignment1.cob:7: error: invalid indicator 'i' at column 7
assignment1.cob:8: error: invalid indicator 'g' at column 7
assignment1.cob:10: error: invalid indicator 'u' at column 7
assignment1.cob:11: error: invalid indicator 'a' at column 7
assignment1.cob:12: error: invalid indicator 'k' at column 7
assignment1.cob:14: warning: line not terminated by a newline [-Wothers]
assignment1.cob:14: error: invalid indicator 'r' at column 7
assignment1.cob:9: error: PROGRAM-ID header missing
assignment1.cob:9: error: PROCEDURE DIVISION header missing
assignment1.cob:9: error: syntax error, unexpected PICTURE
user@DESKTOP-57BGLNH:~$
```

***For context,**

I am in VSC, I open the remote window and create a new file with the following code:

```
identification division.
program-id. Assignment1.

environment division.
configuration section.

data division.
working-storage section.
01 out pic x(11) value "Hello World".
procedure division.
    display out.
    goback.

end program Assignment1.

File> Save.
```

Open new terminal, and use `pwd` and `ls` to ensure I am in the right directory, as you can see "/home/user" is the directory where file "testdoc.cob" is located, as per ls command. I then use `cobc -x testdoc.cob` to compile, and then I get these series of errors.  Why is this? and where am I going wrong?

I've tried repeating the process in new folders with different .extentions, all end in the same result.

Comment: I haven't programmed Cobol in over 40 years, but I think you have to indent the code. The first field of the code is for line numbers. It's left over from when COBOL was entered on punch cards.

Comment: do you mean each line of the code should be tabbed over? or just a specific column?

Comment: Also note that these messages are created by `cobc` (the GnuCOBOL compiler) - upgrading that shows a single note that the layout is automatically switched to free-form reference-format and all errors therefore are gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is code in free-form reference-format, which was standardized with COBOL2002, the "historical" fixed-form reference-format uses a layout in which there is a "sequence" column 1-6, an indicator column 7 and depending on the standard used the code goes to column 12-72 or also includes 8-11 (where previously only some declarations went).
"Old" code you see will be often in fixed-form reference-format and as some COBOL tools still only support this format, you may consider still using it for new code. When coding in a group (or a "COBOL shop") you will commonly have rules about what to use.

To learn more about formats see the [Programmer's Guide](https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/HTML/gnucobpg.html#Format-of-Program-Source-Lines) for the compiler you use.

GnuCOBOL 3.2 compiles this with

> assignment.cob:1: note: free format detected

for earlier versions either explicit set it by passing the command line option `--free` or, as noted in the Programmer's Guide, use a compiler directive:

```
       >> SOURCE FORMAT IS FREE
```

(that starts in column 8) is the COBOL standard way to set this, Micro Focus COBOL (which has quite a big market in COBOL on PC) defines it as:

```
       $SET SOURCE-FORMAT "FIXED"
```

(GnuCOBOL supports both)